# Glassfish admin page login

Tags: glassfish

I have no idea what is going on here. Installed glassfish 3.1.1 onto my windows server, created domain (with admin and password) during the installation phase, everything seems to have went smoothly.

But now when I try to log into the admin web (port 4848), my credentials that I created for my domain during installation do not work.

Tried all the default password suggestions (adminadmin, changeit, ), but nothing works.

I even successfully changed my password with the change-password command in console but still nothing.

Please, help!

Comment: Ok not sure what was going on.

So i deleted the domain, created a new one with no credentials, still did not work. So i deleted it again and again created a new one but with a username and password. Now its working...

Comment: Nope cancel that. Is still happening after a reboot. This is frustrating...

Comment: Happening to me too. Doesn't even work after a fresh install. Something weird is going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799915/lost-admin-password-for-glassfish-server-on-windows-7/12081657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK 1.7.0_02 is the culprit: [GLASSFISH-18148](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18148). Downgrade to 1.7.0_01.